# azure-active-directory file picker redirect_uri issue

Tags: onedrive

i try to use onedrive file picker like below,

```
    function launchOneDrivePicker() {
            var odOptions = {
                clientId: "xxxx",
                action: "query",
                multiSelect: true,
                advanced: {
                    endpointHint: "api.onedrive.com",
                    response_type: "code"
                },
                success: function (files) {
                    alert("selected file id: " + files.value[0].id);
                    debugger;
                    UploadFileFromUrl(files.value[0].url, files.value[0].fileName, "one drive");
                    /* success handler */
                },
                cancel: function () {
                    debugger; /* cancel handler */
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    debugger; /* error handler */
                }
            }
            OneDrive.open(odOptions);
        }
```

but when i change the action from query to download, throw that issue

```
invalid_request: The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.
```